# Scrapy encoding and json formatting issue

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using python 3.6x version and scrapy to extract some online data.

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "extract"

start_urls = [
    'https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10174455955',
]

def parse(self, response):
    question_title = response.css("div.ptsQes P::text").extract_first().strip()
    question_content = response.css("div.ptsQes P.queTxt::text").extract()
    best_answer = response.css("div.mdPstd.mdPstdBA.othrAns.lstLast.clrfx div.ptsQes p.queTxt::text").extract()
    filename = 'extract.json'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(question_title.encode("utf8")),
        f.write(question_content[0].encode("utf8")),
        f.write(best_answer[0].encode("utf8"))
    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

I have tried to extract data from the code written above, but come across with several issues if anyone would help will really be appreciated.

1. How can I make it into json format, i.e. ['question_title' : 'XXX','question_content':'XXX','best_answer': 'xxx'] since I can only get some strings
2. Why couldn't I put encode("utf8") after response.css..., i.e.

> response.css("div.ptsQes
>   P::text").extract_first().strip().encode("utf8")

It doesn't work. **It didnt encode any data** but leave me the unicode.

Thanks if anyone know about that.

Comment: you can have a look to the python encode error handling [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.register_error)

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your data json formatted. I'd use the builtin json library.

```
import json
json.dumps({'question_title' : question_title,
            'question_content':'question_content',
            'best_answer': 'best_answer'}).encode('utf8')
```